# How to make your website https only?

Tags: html, ssl

I've got a working SSL certificate, but the only way for a person to visit my https website is by typing "https://" in the search bar. I've got a .htacces file that contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

And I also tried this line of code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But neither of them seem to work.

I've also read that there is a meta tag that sends all users to your https no matter what. But still have yet to find what the meta tag looks like.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: Server configuration issues are off topic here and are best asked on https://serverfault.com You should delete this and ask over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is correct - you will need rewrite rules on your webserver for to make the site HTTPS only

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Please take a look at the following documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Regarding why your rules are not working - you need to know the context of .htaccess file, from documentation:

> .htaccess files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way
>   to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file,
>   containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a
>   particular document directory, and the directives apply to that
>   directory, and all subdirectories thereof.

it is however better not to use .htaccess at all if possible since it has negative performance implications and the same thing can be achieved with `<Directory>` blocks. All of that is in here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Regarding the meta tag - all you need to do is add something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://yoursite.com/">
```

The meta tag is definitely not the best practice of HTTP-2-HTTPS redirection due to the fact that it is easy to circumvent and outside of webmasters control since it's a client side redirect.

Comment: The `<meta>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: Correct, I pasted it w/o inspecting the end. Corrected in the answer.